# Referencing (not Bibliography) in Harvard Style using Write Latex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, harvard-style

I am relatively new to Latex and I am trying to write my first project thesis. I am using WriteLatex, which is an online Latex environment. I was successful in obtaining the references from many sites, imported them into a .bib file in Bibtex and cite them in Author Year title format. My problem arises when I cannot see the References at the bottom in Harvard style. What I want to see is this

```
[Alpaydin,2004] Ethem Alpaydin, Introduction to Machine Learning, MIT Press, 2004.
```

What I get is just this under the name Bibliography

```
Ethem Alpaydin, Introduction to Machine Learning, MIT Press, 2004.
```

I am using the following packages

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{Ref} %My .bib file
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Edit: The Bibliography files are of the format:

```
@book{alpaydin2004introduction,
  title={Introduction to machine learning},
  author={Alpaydin, Ethem},
  year={2004},
  publisher={MIT press}
}
```

Can someone please help me get the Harvard style referencing even at the end of the document in the style I mentioned above. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! You seem to be using the `plainnat` style but perhaps that is not what you want and you should choose a different one? Note that your code cannot be used to reproduce the problem you describe since you do not include any bibliography entries in your question.

Comment: Could you kindly suggest what style I should use for that.

Comment: @cfr - In the present case, the solution doesn't require using a different bibliography style. Instead, all that's required is *not* loading the `natbib` package.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. It is a while since I used `natbib`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the appearance of the entries in the references, keep using the `plainnat` bibliography style but do *not* load the `natbib` package. You'll get:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % to keep output all on one page
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,graphicx}
%\usepackage{natbib} %% deliberately commented out
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Ref.bib}
@book{alp:04,
  author   = "Ethem Alpaydin", 
  title    = "Introduction to Machine Learning",
  publisher= "MIT Press",
  year     = 2004,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\cite{alp:04}
\bibliography{Ref}
\end{document}
```

---

If you do not want square brackets surrounding the citation callout, i.e., if you want it to look like `Alpaydin(2004)`, you should also provide the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\renewcommand\citeleft{}
\renewcommand\citeright{}
```

---

If you did load `natbib` -- and, of course, didn't load the `cite` package as well -- you'd get the following look, which is, I gather, not what you want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mico, it works!I never knew I should change that.

Comment: One more question is how did you name the section as 'References', mine shows 'Bibliography' but I don't want that. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Nikki_Champ - My code produces the header named "References" because I used the `article` document class, just to keep the output all on one page. If you switch to the `report` class, you'll get "Bibliography" as the header.